# Is calc(--x - y) a valid CSS syntax?

Tags: css, minify, css-calc

I am using Visual Studio and its bundle functionality to minify CSS files.

It returned an error when it found the following instruction:

```
.ui.card .image > .ui.ribbon.label,
.ui.image > .ui.ribbon.label {
  left: calc(--0.05rem - 1.2em);
}
```

Thy is why I wonder if that is a valid CSS syntax, if I get rid of that "extra" minus sign everything goes good.

Comment: no , this isn't

Comment: What is `--0.05rem` supposed to do? The `--` syntax is reserved for [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), e.g. `--myFavoriteColor: red; background-color: var(--myFavoriteColor)`

Comment: That snippet comes from [semantic.css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist), if that is not valid, why are they using it?

Comment: Your minifier is causing the issue, I bet.

Comment: If you can make it ignore certain rules, or something, that would be good--there's some error with translating variables, it looks like, perhaps only when it's a negative number, or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Is `calc(--x - y)` a valid CSS syntax?

[The `--` prefix is used to define custom properties:](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#defining-variables)

> A ***custom property*** is any property whose name **starts with two dashes** (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), like `--foo`. The *`<custom-property-name>`* production corresponds to this: it’s defined as any valid identifier that starts with two dashes, except `--` itself, which is reserved for future use by CSS. Custom properties are solely for use by authors and users; CSS will never give them a meaning beyond what is presented here.

**A example using custom properties:**

```css
:root {
  --back-color: red;
}
p {
  background: var(--back-color);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello StackOverflow</p>
```

**So in your case (a calculation `-1 * -1 = 1`) the `--` is not valid.**

---

## Why are they (Semantic UI) using it?

The [semantic.css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/blob/master/semantic.css) file is the result of a LESS script ([semantic.less](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/semantic.less)). On the following screenshot you see the source of the `--`. So it looks like a bug or unexpected behavior:

[image]

---

## Let's try to reproduce this using LESS.

The following code is built like the semantic.less code:

```
@test: -0.05em;

.test {
    margin-left: calc(-@test);
}
```

which compiles to the following CSS (with `--` again):

```
.test {
    margin-left: calc(--0.05em);
}
```

The same code but without using the `calc` function:

```
@test: -0.05em;

.test {
    margin-left: -@test;
}
```

which compiles to the following CSS:

```
.test {
    margin-left: 0.05em;
}
```

**How to fix it (a possible fix)?**

```
@test: -0.05em;

.test {
    margin-left: calc(@test * -1);
}
```

which compiles to the following CSS:

```
.test {
    margin-left: calc(-0.05em * -1);
}
```

On LESS earlier 3.0 math is performed within the `calc` function. So [`calc(-@test)` compiles to `calc(0.05em)`](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/xk1qvdh7/). But since LESS 3.0 no math is performed within `calc` so [`calc(-@test)` compiles to `calc(--0.05em)`](https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/7z09vmny/):

> Essentially, the calc() bug was recently fixed and no math is performed within calc(). But functions within calc() will still perform math on their arguments (unless the inner function is also calc).
>   **source:** https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3221#issuecomment-398610371

Comment: Thanks! wow, that is pretty weird, [semantic.css](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist) is implementing that kind of syntax.

Comment: @Jamo I do think it's rather that VS (VS Code)'s minifier is causing an issue.

Comment: @D_N, So do you believe that syntax is correct and that is more a VS issue?

Comment: @Jamo it depends on what comes before it. the minifier seems to be interpreting the variable, and there is either an issue where the variable is declared (on semantic's part, or yours) or it's just a straightforward bug on the minifier's part. the OUTPUT is wrong, as shown here. **`--` doesn't work in the output as shown.**

Comment: @D_N, well, I believe there's an issue on variable declaration and transformation I guess, from LESS to CSS, per Sebastian's answer.

Comment: @Sebastian Brosch, Thanks! That was occurred there, by the way, what thing did you use to transform to CSS?

Comment: ... but using http://winless.org/online-less-compiler or https://lesstester.com/ is doing the right. maybe depends on version or options.